# Jenkins curl command returns XML instead of calling job

Tags: xml, windows, curl, jenkins, build

I'm calling a Jenkins job remotely using a curl command, like this:

```
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\curl.exe" -X POST -u [user]/[password] http://[server]:8080/job/[job]/buildWithParameters?NODE=[node]
```

The Jenkins job is never run. Instead on the command line, the command returns a big chunk of XML (I cut out most of the middle section, but it's mostly references to js and css files):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html><html><head data-rooturl="" resURL="/static/a7b46c37" data-resu
rl="/static/a7b46c37">
    <title>Jenkins</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/a
7b46c37/css/layout-common.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/s

...

    function showTranslationDialog() {
      if(!translation.launchDialog)
        loadScript("/static/a7b46c37/plugin/translation/dialog.js");
      else
        translation.launchDialog();
      return false;
    }</script></div></div></div></footer></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The user didn't have Build permission on the job. Once I gave it Build permission, the command didn't return any XML, and the Jenkins job ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate with basic auth, you should use:

```
-u [user]:[password]
```

instead of:

```
-u [user]/[password]
```

- if the job you're trying to run has it's own token, add the query param to the end of the url:

  &token=[token]